# Problems with Pi 3 upgrade

Tags: update

I just received my first Pi 3, loaded the NOOBS software on the SD card, installed Raspbian, configured my localization settings, and connected to the internet via Wi-Fi (all without any problems; very easy to follow instructions).

Next I followed the instructions for updating the SD card using `sudo apt-get update` no problems again.  I then used the `sudo apt-get upgrade` and received the following message: [image: error message]

What is this?

I also can't get my NoIR camera v2 to work.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question about the camera. It looks like a separate problem, so please ask a new question with details.

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly it's a non-critical message listing the release notes for the packages being upgraded.

It's displayed in a page viewer program, so:

- press <kbd>space</kbd> to scroll the message down page by page;
- press <kbd>q</kbd> to end the viewer and proceed.

Unless you see an error at the bottom there is nothing to worry about. There might also be some guidance if you need to do something for a specific package.

It might look difficult for someone not experienced, but basically all you should do is to read the message and understand it.